# Need help binding events to a jQuery template

Tags: jquery

When I click the minus button I would like the value inside the textbox to decrement, and when I click the plus button I would like the value inside the textbox to increment. I'm using a jQuery template that takes in JSON to automatically populate.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <div style="display:block;" id="${getNextId()}">
     <div class="adjuster">
       <button id='minusbutton'>-</button>
       <input id='quantityText' class="enterQuantity" type=text 
             style="width:40px; margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px" />
       <button id='plusbutton'>+</buton>
     </div> 
     <div class="productName">
       <div>${productname}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="quantity">
         <span style="font-weight:bold;">${quantity}</span>
         <span> Remaining</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

If I add onclick events to the buttons in the markup, how can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/GAfyW/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="plusOne">Click to Increment</div>
<div id="minusOne">Click to Decrement</div>
<span type="text" id="valueContainer"/>0</span>
```

JS placed within onload block:

```
$('#plusOne').bind('click', function() {
  var value = $('#valueContainer').html();
  // Increment the value
  $('#valueContainer').html(parseInt(value)+1);
});

$('#minusOne').bind('click', function() {
  var value = $('#valueContainer').html();
  // Decrement the value
  $('#valueContainer').html(parseInt(value) - 1);
});
```

In here:

- 'plusOne' = 'plusButton';
- 'minusOne' = 'minusButton';
- 'valueContainer' = the span you've used to house the quantity.